# Android: clean up back stack without causing Fragments to go through their lifecycle methods

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using tabbed navigation in my app, and I want to remove all FragmentTransactions from the back stack when the user selects a tab, without causing the Fragments to go through their lifecycle.

Calling:

`mFragmentMgr.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);`

is supposed to clear the entire back stack, unfortunately, this causes any Fragments that were on the stack to go through their lifecycle methods, and I am getting an NPE because `getActivity()` is returning null.

Is there a way to clear the back stack without this side effect?